# Not able to build Xcode project on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium, xcodebuild

I am facing a strange issue:

I am trying to build using this xcode command
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination ‘id={deviceID}' test

But every time I run this command I see an unusual prompt that shows up in the next line --
quote]

I am not sure what quote means and what I am expected to enter. I tried entering other device attributes but still it din help me .

Could some one please help me?

Comment: is provisioning profile set correctly?

Comment: Yes it is set correctly..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your provided information you are trying to start a test on a real device. Tests are executed on simulator only, which is why Xcode tells you it's not able to build your project.

Try something like this instead:

```
xcodebuild \
  -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj \
  -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.1' \
  test
```

As you can see this command tries to build your project on an iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 8.1 installed. You can define this to your liking (e.g. OS=13.0 or another iPhone/iPad).

You can give these reads a try, too, for more examples and a better understanding:

- https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/running-tests-from-the-terminal/
- https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/run-xcode-unit-tests-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Glad I could help :)